# Theme not applying for new products page

Tags: magento1.9.2.4

I have added new custom theme to my project. Everything working fine. But, when I click the any one of product in  product list my new theme not applying in that product page. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to open product in admin and check if Custom Design or Page Layout are changed https://monosnap.com/file/uYAfTXNUxDnsBni7KliBVYD8kXHZIO#

if Custom design is changed - this will mean that Magento will use other theme for product view page
if Page Layout is changed - this will mean Magento will look file for layout (ex. template/page/1column.phtml) in your theme firstly and after that (if not found) - will look for it in default magento theme (or theme which is choosed as Default in Admin - System - Configuration - Design)